# Python reshape dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a problem reshaping my dataframe, which contains the shopping history of someone.

`d = {'0': ["cars", "clothes","food"], '1': ["electronics", "food","food"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`

now i want to make new dataframe where each row contains the last category of interest and the new one so a 2 column dataframe that looks like this:

`d = {'0': ["cars", "clothes"],'1':["clothes","food"] '2': ["electronics", "food"],'3':["food","food"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`

I can do this with for loops but since i have a big dataset this takes to long. Is there any faster way to do this?

`

```
#create pairs from each path
totalArr = list()
for pa in dataset['channel']:
   newArr = list()
    for ind,chan in enumerate(pa):
        maxlen = len(pa)
        if(ind < maxlen-1):
            newArr.append([pa[ind],pa[ind+1]])
    totalArr.append(newArr)

fromToDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['from','to'])

for a in totalArr:
    for b in a:
        fromToDf= fromToDf.append(pd.DataFrame(data={'from':[str(b[0])],'to':[str(b[1])]}))
```

`

Comment: I didn't get it very well. Maybe if you showed us the way you managed to do it with a `for`...

Comment: I added my for loop

Comment: Edit the question. This place isn't good for exhibiting code.

Comment: The code you posted references columns such as `channels` which don't exist in your sample DataFrame. Please modify the sample DataFrame, `df` so it can be plugged into your code. Perhaps it will help us understand the result you are looking for.